# About multiple series and interchange of summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

I am interested in finding some reference books or papers where the question of conditions for the interchange of summation in multiple series is treated. In other words, under which conditions we can rearrange the order or summation in expressions of the type

$$\sum_{i_1}\sum_{i_2}\cdots\sum_{i_n}a(i_1,i_2,\cdots, i_n),$$
where the indexes $i_j$ are in $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$, the coefficients $a(i_1,i_2,\cdots, i_n)$ are complex numbers, and the whole series is not necessarily absolutely convergent.

So far, I have only found explanations applied to double series. Can anyone provide some titles?

Comment: What do you mean "multiple series"? If it is multiple nested summations, take them on one by one.

Comment: The question was updated to clarify what I meant.

Comment: The theorems for double summation should also be applicable here, swapping each pair of sums one at a time. However, verifying e.g. the conditions of Fubini-Tonelli for nested sums is quite difficult (in my experience). As for stronger theorems compared to just double sum Fubini-Tonelli, I don't know. I've tried looking for them, but didn't turn up much.

Comment: If for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a finite set $J$ of tuples $i=(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_n)$ such that $\left\lvert\sum_{i\in K}a(i)\right\rvert<\epsilon$ for every finite set of tuples $K$ disjoint from $J,$ then the iterated sum is well defined, and has the same value for any rearrangement, by Bourbaki, *General Topology*, Chapter III, $\S5,$ Theorems 1 and 2. (I hope that's correct! It's not something I've studied. If it's the sort of thing you're looking for, I'll read the passage more carefully and try to write it up as an answer, unless this comment suffices, or someone else writes it up.)

Comment: By problem 5.3.4(c) of Dieudonne, *Foundations of Modern Analysis*, any commutatively convergent series of complex numbers is absolutely convergent - so the previously cited theorems may be too restrictive for your application.  I'll get me coat.

Comment: As a matter of interest (if I may ask a question in a comment): is there a theorem on the interchange of summation in double series that doesn't require absolute convergence (or finiteness of all but one of the index sets)?

Comment: Calum, Theorem 7.5 in Double sequences and Double series, by E. D Habil, is the only one I was able to find not requiring absolute convergence. Will check the references you mentioned, thanks!

Comment: I hope that you or someone else will look into generalising the results in Habil's paper. I don't have enough time or energy at the moment, so I'll just remark briefly that the theorems in Bourbaki and Dieudonne (and the exercises in Apostol, *Mathematical Analysis,* 2nd ed. 1974) don't help with even such a simple example as $\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{mn}=(\log2)^2,$ so your question remains very much open, particularly as it pertains to conditionally convergent series.